# Mobile Phone Number format in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

Was wondering if phone number format matters for Marketing Cloud Journey Builder?  I did a test where I put my mobile number and inside the data extension I had data type phone.  My number was just basic numbers - and it seemed to have worked, but I also see numbers that have
(999)9999999 or
+999999999 or 
9999999999 and so on

Does MC still accept numbers with parentheses?  Also does the number have to have an area code for it to work?

Answer (score 3):

Please find the detailed information from this official documentation link.

> **[Data Extensions Data Types in Email Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_extension_data_types.htm&type=5)**

And to answer your question "Does MC still accept numbers with parentheses?".
Below is the answer from the same official documentation.
[image]